# Copy-pasting text between different applications is randomly working on 22.04

Tags: clipboard, 22.04

Using Ubuntu 22.04, I sometime face some annoying behaviour: when copy e.g. a file content from gedit to Firefox, the paste action is pasting what I last copied, e.g. 1h ago, in Firefox, and it's not pasting what I've just copied seconds ago from gedit.

I took gedit and Firefox as example, but the same occurs between other applications.

But within the application I copied the text, if I paste it back, everything goes fine, so it's there, somewhere in the clipboard, but it's as if this clipping area wasn't shared among all applications.

Is there anything I can do to fix that? Am I the only one to suffer it?

Info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ uname -mor
5.15.0-25-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
```